# Dynamic Excelformula using jquery and php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when calculating dynamic formula,i have a form when remove cursor from calculated field function will cal with formula parameter value.here fields are dynamic means we can't estimate the field id or class for getting vlaues.i will provide code below..

```
function inlineclick(formula, element) {
  var xyz = formula.split('*').join(' ').split('%').join(' ').split('+').join(' ').split('-');
  var xyz1 = (xyz[0].split(' '));
  for (var count = 0; count < xyz1.length; count++) {

    var value1 = $('.' + xyz1[count] + '').val();
  }
  $("input[name='" + element.name + "']").val(eval(formula));
}
```

i want split formula,based on splited name have to fetch that value and calculate formula using that values.